# async-std write_all does not write data to disk immediately

Tags: rust

I have the following code in rust:

```rs
use anyhow::{Result, Error};
use async_std::fs::{File, OpenOptions};
use async_std::io::{ReadExt, WriteExt};

async fn open_log_file() -> Result<File, Error> {
    // Create the file data that will be written to disk.
    let mut file_bytes = [0u8; FILE_MAGIC.len()];
    file_bytes[..].copy_from_slice(FILE_MAGIC.as_bytes());

    // Write the file data to disk.
    let mut f = File::create(FILE_NAME).await.context("unable to create file")?;
    f.write_all(&file_bytes).await.context("unable to write file magic")?;

    // return the file handle
    Ok((f))
}
```

The problem is that this code will not write anything to disk if you just let it run. If you send a kill signal to the program, it will eventually write all of the data to disk. And if you call f.write_all() a few more times, some of the data eventually makes it to disk but in seemingly arbitrary packets.

But if you just let it hang, it can wait several hours and your data will not be written to disk until you close the program / close the file handle. Calling `f.flush()` after the write_all call does **not** seem to help.

How can I ensure that somewhere in the stack a syscall is being made to actually write the data to disk while still not blocking the thread? It's very confusing to me that the future will resolve without ever actually writing data to disk.

Comment: Calling `f.flush()` doesn't work but calling `f.flush().await` does work, this is my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Calling `f.flush()` does work, except you need to call `f.flush().await`. Just calling a naked `f.flush()` will compile without error and run without error, which is perhaps a separate problem but at least my code works as intended now.

Comment: You're expected to get a warning for that, like here - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=57c7170f86172ef187238e28c7692f0d. If you haven't, it might even be a bug.